# Can I cancel a Zend Controller action in the init() method?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller

During `Zend_Controller_Action::init()`, is there a way to cancel the action (so it won't be called)?

```
<?php
class JsonApiController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    function init()
    {
        // try JSON decoding the raw request body
        if ($jsonDecodingFailed) {
            echo '{"error":"invalid JSON"}';
            $this->_cancelAction(); // something like this exist?
        }
    }
}
```

My current workaround is to make an empty `nullAction()` method and call `$this->_forward('null')` to forward to it.

Comment: What should happend when the request is canceled? Do you want to send any specific headers or render a view script?

Comment: Gordon, the view/layout is disabled. I could `exit()`, but I don't want to kill the whole post-dispatch process.

Comment: but what do you want to return? If you dont want to simply `exit` what should happen? You say you are using a workaround but the question is for what? What does nullAction do? And why do you consider it a workaround? Actually, I have a hard time understanding what your question or your aim is.

Comment: My goal is to jump directly from the `init` (which in this special case sends the whole response) to the post-dispatch process. I'm starting to think `init` is the wrong place for this decoding/validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres nothing wrong in using $this->_forward() inside the init() (if the method you want to forward to is inside the same controller as the init()), this will simply change the request object's controller / action (overwrite what has been set via the router).

An alternative to this would be to create a Zend_Controller_Plugin as it looks like you are handling unexpected errors. 
Have a look at the Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler implementation.
So instead of forwarding to another action you would throw an exception, and have your custom plugin check in postDispatch() if the response contains eny expections, and if it does simply edit the current Request object to show your "cancel" action.

```
$request->setDispatched(false)
        ->setControllerName("error")
        ->setActionName("jsonDecoding");
```

The last way could be to just throw a exit after the echo "{error: "invalid json"}" not very nice but you will avoid the overload of having another dispatch iteration.

Comment: Thanks. I found I can use `setErrorHandler()` on the default ErrorHandler plugin to have exceptions handled in the same controller

Comment: I temporarily used `exit()`, but besides not being a very nice solution, it also makes it impossible to write functional tests because the tests will also get killed at this point (and it took me a while to find out why the tests didn't return any results). Another reason for avoiding `exit()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would throw an exception (and then catch it in error controller) - that's what you do when there is non-recoverable error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone that is still looking for solution you can try this:
Add a flag stating whether there is an error or not and override dispatch method. If the flag is set, do not invoke `parent::dispatch`.

This works the way I want it to. My reason was that I am making an abstract API controller, which by default checks for an API key in request, if its not there - controller should respond with error and complete request successfully.

E.g.

```
abstract class Api_Controller extends Zend_Rest_Controller{
 private $responded = false;
 public function init() {
    parent::init();
    if(!$this->isKeyValid())
       $this->respond("invalid key"); // this would set flag to true and handle error
 }
 public function dispatch($action) {
    // if an error occured and it was dispatched, do not call action method, just finish request
    if(!$this->responded)
        parent::dispatch($action);
 }
}
```

For me this seems like a clean solution.

Comment: excelente:). Just a little correction: $this->responded("invalid key");

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html) (under "Pre- and Post-Dispatch Hooks"), calling _forward() in preDispatch() will skip the action.

Specifically about preDispatch(): "its primary purpose is to make decisions about whether or not the requested action should be dispatched. If not, you should then _forward() to another action, or throw an exception."